# max file upload limit

Tags: nginx, php

I have a form that has a file uploader
I just want to show a message containing file size error message when the file is too large but i have the following scenario :

when the max-file exceeds the `nginx` it auto respond with nginx error message and while i'm uploading it by ajax i can show nothing

I tried increasing the `nginx` file limit and restricting the `php.ini` size limit 
it went so perfect because the php return a status code describing the error and from it I can show my own message, the problem with this way is that the php.ini has the following two attributes:

```
post_max_size  = 15M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

if the max_post_size was exceeded (16M) the file is ignored and the back end has no idea if it was an empty file or ignored while if it was only exceeds the upload_max_filesize (12M) the error status is available

so how can I by pass the max_post_size ?

Comment: maybe a silly question but are you restarting both php-fpm and nginx after making your changes to the conf files?

Comment: Yes for sure Mr.@jnolte, thanks for the hint ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was solved by doing the following ...

```
if(!$file && Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest && !$_POST){
    return $this->render('upload_error', array('errors'=>"File too large. Maximum file size is 10 MB)"));
  }
```

on the application layer